# Php issue with -1 conversion

Tags: php, apache-flex

I am sending value -1 as a argument for the function through remoteobject from flex to php file in live application. In live php file,i am getting as 4294967295 instead of -1.

In flex i do this:

```
private var techid:Number = -1; 
remobjorder.sample.send(techid);
```

and in php

```
public function sample($techid){
  echo $techid; //here i am getting this 4294967295 value instead of -1 
}
```

I cant get the reason why it is converted.

Let me know any valid reason and alternative solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u show your code....

Comment: public function sample($techid){ // here i am getting that value} In local file i am getting this correct value. Live server only problem

Comment: @venkat: Rather than posting a tiny bit of your code unformatted in the comments section, think about what parts are responsible and edit your question, adding them there.

Comment: @AndreschSerj: From flex i am calling the php function using remote object method like this manner ----private var tech_ID:Number = -1; remobjorder.sample.send(techid);   and in php public function sample($techid){echo $techid;//here i am getting that 4294967295 value instead of -1 }......this is live server issue only...runs fine in local system

Comment: I am not only getting the different numbers instead of -1. When we are accessing -1 from any remote object we are getting different 10 digit number. In this case for -1 the value would be 4294967295 ,if you are increase the negative value (ie. -10) we can get decreased value of that 10 digit number (ie. 4294967285).

Comment: @venkat What happens if you change the flex `techId` to int instead of Number?

Comment: @Brian : Flex techid not at all a problem here. I got the 10 digit value for every negative value. Because, i am using flex as a front end. so amf parser will not allow negative value. I guess this is a problem.

Comment: @venkat: It does sound like the amf parser could be converting it as an unsigned int.  I did find this [blog](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweflex.wordpress.com%2F2011%2F10%2F28%2Fsending-negative-numbers-through-amfphp%2F&ei=wEtNU6OCDIabyASh0YLYCw&usg=AFQjCNFu72n8xfHXyHXiN8SvjXDgQxD6bw) that might help.

Answer (score 1):

That might be a 32bits-64bits issue.

As a workaround, send the number as a string and convert it back to a number in php.